# creating bi-directional transforms with manifold

Tags: clojure

I have a code that constructs a websocket client

```
(require '[aleph.http :as http]
         '[manifold.stream :as stream]
         '[cheshire.core :as json])

(def raw (deref (http/websocket-client url)))
```

and a data channel:

```
(def data (stream/stream))
```

the raw channel returns bytes which can be converted back and forth:

```
(defn to-data [bytes]
  (-> bytes
      (String.)
      (json/parse-string)))

(defn to-raw [data]
  (-> data
      json/generate-string
      (.getBytes)))
```

I'm looking to connect raw and data so the that there is a bi-directional transformation in order to keep data format consistent.

```
 raw|  == [to-data] ==> |data
    |  <== [to-raw] ==  |
```

there is a method called 'connect-via' but I'm not sure how it is used